# How to implement a gallery in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have four images that are aligned side to side. Except the third image is below the second image. Both are aligned to the right of the first image. The fourth image is aligned to the right of the second and third image (which are stacked on top of each other).

See picture:
http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/9802269

How do I implement this in CSS?

I have the following code:

```
<div class="examples">
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/1.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/2.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/3.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/4.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

I want to do this automatically. No hacks using the HTML.

I got them aligned side by side, but I can't figure out how to align the second and third image so that the second image is on top of the third image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .examples {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .example {
            position: absolute;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 33.33%;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }
        .example:nth-child(1) {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url(examples/1.jpg);
        }
        .example:nth-child(2) {
            top: 0;
            left: 33.33%;
            height: 50%;
            background-image: url('examples/2.jpg');
        }
        .example:nth-child(3) {
            top: 50%;
            left: 33.33%;
            height: 50%;
            background-image: url('examples/3.jpg');
        }

        .example:nth-child(4) {
            top: 0;
            left: 66.66%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url('examples/4.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="examples">
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will there always be 4 images?

Comment: Yes There will always be 4 images

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure CSS solution. One caveat, you'll run into [pixel rounding](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) at some sizes, causing images to be off by a pixel or two at some viewport sizes.

```css
    .examples {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .example {
        width: 25%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .example img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .example:nth-child(1) {
      position: relative;
    }
  
    .example:nth-child(3) {
      margin-top: 12.475%;
      margin-bottom:-50%;
    }
    
    .example:nth-child(4) {
      left: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="examples">
   <div class="example"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image1" /></div>
   <div class="example"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200&text=Image2" /></div>
   <div class="example"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200&text=Image3" /></div>
   <div class="example"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image4" /></div>
</div>
```

And a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/4vhq5bvy/)

Comment: this doesn't work. The second and third image overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<div class="examples">
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/1.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/2.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/3.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/4.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.examples {


display:flex;
  width:600px;
  border:1px solid Blue;
}

.example:nth-child(1),
.example:nth-child(4)
{
  flex:0 0 40%;
  background:Pink;
}

.example:nth-child(2),
.example:nth-child(3)
{
  flex:0 0 20%;
  background:cyan;
}

.example:nth-child(3)
{
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:120px;
  margin-left:-120px;
  width:120px;
}

.example img 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Use http://autoprefixer.github.io/ for cross browser support.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

In future it would be polite for you to provide the codepen

Comment: Nice use of flex! This will still result in pixel rounding issues however, correct?

Comment: I don't know @BrettDeWoody but I would have thought that seeing as the image is 100% wide it should be ok?

Comment: Flexbox is unfortunately [not free of pixel rounding issues](https://www.palantir.net/blog/responsive-design-s-dirty-little-secret).

Comment: @BrettDeWoody that is interesting, thanks for that, that is some crazy stuff, but I tend to work with a combination of % and em and it tends to come out fine, that said I haven't done many projects using flex yet. Here is an example of what I mean: http://shop.webaware.com.au/

Answer (score 0):

i think you should wrap the second and third image on a div with a float between the first and fourth image like this:

```
<div class="examples">
  <div class="example"></div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="example-half"></div>
    <div class="example-half"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="example"></div>
</div>
```

then the image on the wrap class has a display block on it

```
.example {
  background:red;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}
.wrap, .example {
  float: left;
}
.example-half {
  background:blue;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.example, .example-half {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

you can do the styling and etc. . hope this helps goodluck

i have created a simple fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mr8kdeef/)

Answer (score 0):

I have found something that works. I don't know if I will work for your photos. Please tell me if it doesn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.example {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.example img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="examples">
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/1.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="example">
        <div class="second"><img src="examples/2.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="third"><img src="examples/3.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/4.jpg" /></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a pure CSS solution without changing the current HTML

Comment: @PotaOnasys You will need to have an extra <div></div> element around the two images. With my knowledge, you cannot do it purely with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not accepting any of the previous answers, here is a plunk that i played with:

http://plnkr.co/edit/di1vBRu0pzzLDbWRtp2K?p=preview

```
CSS
.example img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid;
}

.example2 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    border:1px solid;
}


.example3 img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:8px;
    right:321px;
    border:1px solid;
}

HTML

<div class="examples">
    <div class="example"><img src="examples/1.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="example2"><img src="examples/2.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="example2"><img src="examples/3.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="example3"><img src="examples/4.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done one without touching the html, and one where I added an extra wrapper for div 2 and 3. The one with the extra wrap is the better solution, esp if this must be responsive.

```
.examples{display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-content: center;
-ms-flex-line-pack: center;
align-content: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
box-shadow:9px 12px 8px grey;
height:210px;width:50%;margin:10px auto;
}
```

Link to codepen

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/GoMXaB